# make: undefined reference to `bsaes_cbc_encrypt'

Tags: ubuntu, openssl

I am trying to install OpenSSL on my laptop with Ubuntu (Xenial). However none of the "fips releases" can make it through make. If we talk specifically about **OpenSSL-fips-2_0_13**, this is what make returns before exiting:

```
../libcrypto.a(e_aes.o): In function `aes_init_key':
e_aes.c:(.text+0x267): undefined reference to `bsaes_cbc_encrypt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What does it mean? What additional information should I include in this post?

This is is the set of commands I use to install it:

```
VERSION=OpenSSL-fips-1_2_1

wget --tries=0 --read-timeout=10 https://github.com/openssl/openssl/archive/$VERSION.tar.gz

mkdir $VERSION
tar -xf $VERSION.tar.gz -C $VERSION --strip-components 1

cd $VERSION

INSTALLDIR=`pwd`/library
OPENSSLDIR=$INSTALLDIR/openssl
mkdir -p $INSTALLDIR
./config --prefix=$INSTALLDIR --openssldir=$OPENSSLDIR

sed -i 's/-m486//g' Makefile
make # <------ THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS
make install_sw
```

Comment: Have you downloaded a stable version. Anyway I do not think this should be a problem presented. Still I wouldn't overlook this part. Are you able to compile libgcrypt (tar) alone separately in your system?

Comment: I've tested more OpenSSL releases. This is quiet a new one - some of the releases work, but as I mention in the post none of the "fips" releases works for me.What do you mean by compiling libgcrypt separately?

Comment: Are you following these steps? - https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#FIPS_Capable_Library

Comment: Oh so I have to install something else beforehand? Gonna take a look into that, thanks for now!

Comment: According to the guide: I first build and install the FIPS Object Module (OpenSSL-fips-2_0_13 in this case). That's what I am trying to do if you look at the post. And it fails, I have no idea why.